# How can I set text direction RightToLeft in ms word document in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I create a word document in c# with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

I want display my Arabic text in rtl(RightToLeft) direction. How can I set text direction to rtl ?

In my below code, I change Alighnment, But I can't change direction. Please Help me!

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
object objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
Word.Paragraph wordParagraph = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(ref objMissing);
wordParagraph.Range.Font.Name = "B Titr";
wordParagraph.Range.Font.Size = 14;
WordParagraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment =  Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
wordParagraph.Range.Text = "My Arabic text";
wordParagraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
wordParagraph.ReadingOrder = WdReadingOrder.wdReadingOrderRtl;
```

Comment: Yes, but it's LeftToRight still !

Comment: @  a_ahmadi :i have the same problem,did you find a solution?

Comment: I use this : wordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
oDoc.Paragraphs.ReadingOrder = Word.WdReadingOrder.wdReadingOrderRtl;
```

where `oDoc` is a `Word._Document` instance